# Load mp3 in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview, nsdata

I've an `NSData` obtained from a base64 `NSString`

```
NSString * fileBytes = @"...."; //base 64 string
NSData * bytes = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:fileBytes options:0];
```

The I load the `NSData` into a `UIWebView`

```
[self.webView loadData:bytes
              MIMEType:@"audio/mpeg3"
      textEncodingName:@"UTF-8"
               baseURL:nil];
```

but this is what I see

[image]

I use the same procedure per many file types (PDF, png, jpg, doc, dock, xls ecc), and works perfectly.

Ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recently I had such a situation and I searched a lot. At the end I found two ways to do that.

1. Most nice way: Simply implement your code using [MPMoviePlayerController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953)

   ```
   MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: myURL];
   [player prepareToPlay];
   [player.view setFrame: myView.bounds];  // player's frame must match parent's
   [myView addSubview: player.view];
   // ...
   [player play];
   ```
2. IF you really want to use UIWebView then think about embedded HTML5 `<audio>` tag.

   `<audio controls>
       <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
       <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
       Your browser does not support the audio element.
   </audio>`

and load the HTMLString with the method

```
- (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL
```

but personally I would prefer the first solution with autoplay enabled.